# how can i wait for all chained Begin methods to complete when AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne() is called?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, .net-2.0

When BeginGetBlockHeight is called, it only ever runs asynchronously and i think its because the first Async call does actually complete, but the WaitHandle is unaware of the deeper async calls, hence it 'thinks' all the work is complete, and the main thread continues. however, i need to wait until all sub level tasks complete. How can this be done? i understand it likely means implementing a custom IAsyncResult that contains the state of each child thread, but how to do that i really dont know. any help would be greatly appreciated.

NOTE: i cannot use Task or Await, or anything that isnt compatible with .NET2.0

the whole code snippet can be seen here:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using CSharp2nem;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
public class Wrapper
{
    private byte[] Buffer = new byte[20000];
    public Wrapper()
    {
        Con = new Connection();
    }

    private void ReadStream(Action<ResponseAccessor<string>> callback, Stream stream, int len)
    {
        stream.BeginRead(Buffer, len, 20000, ar =>
        {
            try
            {
                int readLen = stream.EndRead(ar);

                if (readLen == 0)
                {
                    stream.Close();

                    callback(new ResponseAccessor<string>
                    {
                        Content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Buffer, 0, len)
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    var temp = Buffer;

                    Array.Resize(ref temp, Buffer.Length + readLen);

                    Buffer = temp;

                    len += readLen;

                    ReadStream(callback, stream, len);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                stream.Close();

                callback(new ResponseAccessor<string>
                {
                    Ex = ex
                });
            }
        }, null);
    }

    internal IAsyncResult RequestGet(Action<ResponseAccessor<string>> callback, string path, string query = "")
    {
        var http = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Con.GetUri(path, query).Uri);
        http.Accept = "application/json";
        http.ContentType = "application/json";
        http.Method = "GET";

        return http.BeginGetResponse(ar =>
        {
            Stream stream = null;

            try
            {
                var response = http.EndGetResponse(ar);

                stream = response.GetResponseStream();

                ReadStream(callback, stream, 0);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                stream?.Close();
                callback(new ResponseAccessor<string>
                {
                    Ex = ex
                });
            }
        }, null);
    }

    public IAsyncResult BeginGetChainHeight(Action<ResponseAccessor<BlockData.BlockHeight>> callback)
    {
        return RequestGet(body =>
        {
            if (body.Ex != null)
            {
                if (body.Ex.Message.Contains("The remote name could not be resolved") && Con.AutoHost)
                {
                    Con.SetNewHost();

                    BeginGetChainHeight(callback);
                }
                else throw body.Ex;
            }
            else
            {
                callback(new ResponseAccessor<BlockData.BlockHeight>
                {
                    Content = body.Content == null ? null : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BlockData.BlockHeight>(body.Content),
                    Ex = body.Ex
                });
            }
        }, "/chain/height");
    }

    public Connection Con { get; set; }

}

public static void Main()
{
    new Wrapper().BeginGetChainHeight(obj =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("inside");
        Console.WriteLine(obj.Content.height);
    }).AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

    Console.WriteLine("outside");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to have BeginGetChainHeight return a `WaitHandle[]` of all the handles you need to wait for, you could use a `WaitHandle.WaitAll(` then. Also, do you really need all this asyncronisity. Why not just use the synchronous `Read` instead of the `BeginRead` call on the stream?

Comment: Are you aware that `.Net 2.0` is out of support?

Comment: He doesn't know what he using, `Action<T>` was not added until .NET 3.5.  He could use async/await and never know it.  Don't tell the boss :)

Comment: project is targeting .NET framework 2.0 on visual studio and Action is working fine?. needs to be compatible with unity/mono.